# Unsatisfactory output from Tf-Idf

Tags: python-3.x, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I have a document in a text file in 2 lines as shown below. I wanted to apply tf-idf to it and I get the error as shown below, I am not sure where is int object in my file? why would it throw this error?

Env:

`Jupter notebook, python 3.7`

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

file.txt:

```
  Random person from the random hill came to a running mill and I have a count of the hill. This is my house. 

  A person is from a great hill and he loves to run a mill. 

  Sub-disciplines of biology are defined by the research methods employed and the kind of system studied: theoretical biology uses mathematical methods to formulate quantitative models while experimental biology performs empirical experiments.

  The objects of our research will be the different forms and manifestations of life, the conditions and laws under which these phenomena occur, and the causes through which they have been effected. The science that concerns itself with these objects we will indicate by the name biology.
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import spacy
import csv
import collections
import sys
import itertools
import nltk
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from gensim import corpora, models
from stop_words import get_stop_words
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer

data = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep="\n", header=None)

data.dtypes
0    object
dtype: object

data.shape()
4, 1

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(data)
print(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by reading the file like this:

with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f]